# JavaScript error messages showing in eclipse

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, plugins

What plugins do you use when editing html files with JS inserts?

```
<html>
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function fff () {

    hh; //undefined variable

    //unclosed brace
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

I can't make eclipse show any *JavaScript error messages*, though it works well with *.js* files.

*Standart js validator*, *JSDT* and *VJET plugins* work great.
May be I have not turned on all settings of this plugins, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/indigosr2)

Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers is a tool for JavaScript developers creating Web applications, including a JavaScript IDE, tools for JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and XML.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java).

I suggest you that you [install tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) and you check [tern-lint](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter-Lint) plugin which is able to validate your JavaScript files (semantic, type checking errors, but not syntax errors). Here a screenshot with your sample:

[image]